# How do I copy WPF DataGrid seleted cells to the clipboard?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid the following definition:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridFoo"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}"
  IsReadOnly="True"
  SelectionMode="Extended"
  SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
  CopyingRowClipboardContent="DataGridFoo_CopyingRowClipboardContent">
```

This allows me to have the user selected a "region" of cells.
The DataGrid is bound to an observable collection.
The XAML column definitions have some columns hidden, some visible
like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InvoiceID}"
   Header="Invoice ID"
   Visibility="Hidden"
   Width="Auto"/>                
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InvoiceNumber}"
   Header="Invoice Number"
   Visibility="Visible"
   Width="Auto"/>
<DataGridTextColumn 
   Binding="{Binding InvoiceDate,    StringFormat=\{0:MM/dd/yy\}}"                                     
   Header="Invoice Date"
   Visibility="Visible"
   Width="Auto"/>
```

**Consider the "irregular" selection of cells in the DataGrid:**

[image]

I can see this which shows some promise:

```
((System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizedCellInfoCollection)DataGridFoo.SelectedCells)._regions
```

I can examine it's contents through Visual Studio, but can seem to figure out how to access that information programmatically.

I would like to be able copy those cells (in a row/column arrangement perhaps) to the clipboard. This data will be copied both within our app and to external applications.

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: I just tested this and Ctrl+C seems to be working in this scenario without needing to write any extra code (I tested by pasting to Excel).

Comment: Wow. How very right you are. Thanks for point that out.